# SF FLOW - Remove duplicated Opportunity records from Opportunity Collection using Apex Action

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, action, execute-anonymous

I am currently working on a flow in Salesforce Lightning using the Flow Builder and I would like to remove duplicates from an Opportunity collection before updating it.

In order to do so I created the following APEX Action and decided to update the unique Opportunity records contained in its output:

[image: Apex Action + Update]

Here is the commented Invocable Method created for the APEX Action:

```
public class MP_ExtractDistinctOpportunitiesFromList {

@InvocableMethod(label='Distinct list of Opportunities records from Opportunity List' description='Returns Distinct list of Opportunity records from Opportunity List' category='Opportunity')
    public static List<List<Opportunity>> MP_ExtractDistinctOpportunitysFromList(List<List<Opportunity>> OpportunityList) {

        //Instanciating the Output List of lists without duplicates
        List<List<Opportunity>> result = new List<List<Opportunity>>();

        //Iterating through each List Item
        for(List<Opportunity> lo : OpportunityList){

            //Using a set to only contain distinct opportunity records without duplicates
            Set<Opportunity> opportunitySet = new Set<Opportunity>();

            //Using this list to contain the unique opportunity records and add it to the returned list of Lists
            List<Opportunity> distinctOpportunities = new List<Opportunity>();  
  
            //Iterating through each Opportunity elements contained by each list
            for(Opportunity o : lo){   
                //Adding each opportunity to the Set of opportunities to get a set of distinct records           
                opportunitySet.add(o);  
            }

            //Adding the set of distinct opportunities to the opportunity list container
            distinctOpportunities.addAll(opportunitySet);

            //adding the list of opportunities to the returned List of Opportunity Lists
            result.add(distinctOpportunities);   
        }

        //Returning the List of Opportunity Lists
        return result;
    }
}
```

I simulated a call to the above method using Anonymous APEX by giving it a list of Opportunity Lists containing a single list with two duplicated opportunities as a paramater.  Here is the code invoked using Amonymous Apex:

```
//Creating List of Opportunity Lists used as the input parameter 
List<List<Opportunity>> OpportunityList = new List<List<Opportunity>>();

//Creating a unique List with two duplicates
List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>();
Opportunity o1 = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = '0060B00000g124sQAA' LIMIT 1];
opps.add(o1);
opps.add(o1);

//Adding the single Opportunity List with two duplicates to the List of Opportunity List used as the input parameter 
OpportunityList.add(opps);

//Adding a debug statement to visualize the input data
System.debug('INPUT LIST OF OPPORTUNITY LISTS: ' + OpportunityList);

//Instanciating the Output List of lists without duplicates
List<List<Opportunity>> result = new List<List<Opportunity>>();

//Iterating through each List Item
for(List<Opportunity> lo : OpportunityList){

//Using a set to only contain distinct opportunity records without duplicates
    Set<Opportunity> opportunitySet = new Set<Opportunity>();

//Using this list to contain the unique opportunity records and add it to the returned list of Lists
    List<Opportunity> distinctOpportunities = new List<Opportunity>();    

//Iterating through each Opportunity elements contained by each list
    for(Opportunity o : lo){ 

//Adding each opportunity to the Set of opportunities to get a set of distinct records             
        opportunitySet.add(o);  
    }

//Adding the set of distinct opportunities to the opportunity list container
    distinctOpportunities.addAll(opportunitySet);

//Adding the list of opportunities to the returned List of Opportunity Lists
    result.add(distinctOpportunities);   
}
//Adding a debug statement to confirm that the output doesn't contain any duplicates
System.debug('OUTPUT LIST OF OPPORTUNITY LISTS: ' + result);
```

The debug logs look to confirm that the duplicates have been removed as illustrated below:

[image: Debug Log From Anonymous Apex]

When Debugging the flow, the flow fails due to the duplicates not being removed from the Apex Action's output Opportunity Collection and the flow trying to update a list with duplicates:

[image: Duplicated Output from Apex Action]

[image: Flow Error during update]

Can someone help me understand the subtelty hidden behind this error so I could learn how to adjust my workflow on similar use cases?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). I just wanted to thank you for such a well written question, and for including screen shot and code. That is refreshing for a first-time poster. Please fully register and stick around and contribute in other ways.

Comment: My quick look does not reveal anything glaring to me. Two things come to mind: 1] Are you *certain* that your Update Records element is actually using the **output** from your Apex Action?  (You could have accidentally grabbed the wrong variable in the Flow drop down, or maybe before you added the Apex Action you were using the non-unique List and you never updated.) 2] Sets determine uniqueness of objects by their fields. Is there some way that one field on an Opportunity is getting changed in the midst of the Flow? (Maybe change your Apex to just use IDs instead of the entire Opp object.)

Comment: are you sure your Update Records element is using the returned collection from the invocable apex?

Comment: Based on your recommendations, I verifiied the followings: that the update element was getting the output from the APEX Action - **OK**. I also modified the Invocable Apex Method to take Ids instead of Opportunities, modified my Flow accordingly and everythings works now as expected.  **Problem solved!** Thank you so much!